# my react does not render data from my api on mobile but renders on pc ,

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, use-state, array-map

i am working on this project that get data from  my restful api and use it to update the state . It works perfectly on pc/laptop  , but when i access it on mobile it doesn't show anything from the api,  it  only  shows the page and and static file,
in the code below i use map to create the elements from the post state

is there a work around or am i doing it wrong

```
import '../css/pages/Home.css';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Posts from "../components/Posts";

export const Home = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])


    async function fetch_post(link) {
        const res = await fetch(link)
        const data = await res.json()
        setPosts([...data]);

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch_post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/")
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <section className={'intro'}>
                <div className={'intro-con'}>
                    <h1 className="intro-header">Welcome here</h1>
                    <p className="intro-msg">

                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur aut
                        culpa cum distinctio excepturi, fuga hic id praesentium reiciendis similique veniam voluptate
                        voluptates? Accusamus ad aliquam consequuntur cupiditate dolor, dolorem dolores earum eius
                        eligendi fuga illum ipsam molestiae, nulla omnis, praesentium quae quia quibusdam repellat totam
                        voluptate? Ex, molestias, voluptatem?</p>
                    <Link to={'about/'} className={'btn'} style={{width: "max-content"}}>Learn More</Link>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section className="posts-feed contain">

                {posts.map(post => {
                    return (
                        <Posts post={post}/>
                    );
                })}

            </section>
        </>

    )}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using localhost address to fetch data i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.
The backend is running on your pc/laptop so it would work there, but not on mobile. To make it visible on the mobile use your LAN address instead of localhost.
On Windows OS, you can open up cmd and check by this command:
`ip config`
On MacOS, you can fire up your terminal and check by:
`ifconfig`

It would be something like: `192.168.1.12` (just an example).

So inside your useEffect hook, you can use:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch_post("http://192.168.1.12:8000/")
    }, [])
```

Then you will be able to view your data on mobile as well.

Comment: Omg , thank you very much , I didn't even think about that , I feel so dumb

Comment: And sorry I can't upvote you , not enough reputation

Comment: I didn't realize I had to to change the host I'm using on the backend , I only changed the on I'm using on the frontend to make my mobile access , I almost went loco trying to figure out what wrong and you fixed it in a min , thank alot

Comment: @JosephThomasEhigie Hey no worries, glad it unblocked you.